# Where reside the returned records of the mongodb function currentOp()?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

exist any way to know if this function collects information from an accesible collection?

For example these registres:

```js
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(d){if(d.client)print(d.client, d.connectionId)})
```

I was looking at the data in the 'oplog.rs' collection but it didn't seem  contain what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no database collection mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/currentOp/#dbcmd.currentOp) which means that currentOps are most likely held in an internal MongoDB data structure.

Browsing the github MongoDB repository and the body of `currentOp` method leads to [CurOp](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/8bf0a1988427e970c965994c629997a2a357dcd1/src/mongo/db/curop.cpp#L148) C++ class which is simple **in-memory stack** implementation so there's no persistent storage for current ops.

You can also take a look at [system.profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/index.html) if you're trying to build some sort of diagnostic solution which requires persistent storage.